# Counting combinations between two columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

| 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | A |
| C | D |
| C | D |
| D | C |

I want to be able to count the number of instances of a combination like this:

| Letters | Count |
| --- | --- |
| AB | 2 |
| CD | 3 |

So essentially I want to be able to count CD and DC as the same instance for the purposes of counting the number of occurences.

I have tried

`df.groupby(['1','2']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})`

But this does not count AB the same as BA and instead counts their occurences seperately. If anyone has any suggestions on how to do this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't returning the counts to the original df, you can just sort first.

```
df.values.sort()
df['letters'] = df['1'].astype(str) + df['2'].astype(str)
df.groupby('letters').size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Output

```
    letters count
0        AB   2
1        CD   3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Doing this does count both AB and BA as the same which is what I want but then it completely throws the order of these pairs off. On my larger dataset I had zero AA pairs but after doing these commands now I have thousands of them because of the values.sort() has moved the values around without keeping them together with each other. Is there perhaps another solution you can suggest where this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1):

another method similair to Chris's is to use `stack` and `groupby`.

```
s = df.stack().sort_values().groupby(level=0).agg(''.join).to_frame('Letters')

s.groupby('Letters',as_index=False).agg(Count=('Letters','size'))

Letters  Count
0      AB      2
1      CD      3
```